# Showing that $(\mathbb{Z}_6,+)$ and $(U(\mathbb{Z}_7), \cdot)$ are isomorphic groups

Tags: group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

We have to prove that $(\mathbb{Z}_6,+)$ and $(U(\mathbb{Z}_7), \cdot)$ are isomorphic.

I know that they are and the isomorphism is as follows: $f(0)=1, f(1)=3, f(2)=2, f(3)=6, f(4)=4, f(5)=5$.

It is obvious that it is bijective, but how do I prove that this is a homomorphism?

Comment: $\mathbb Z_4$ only has four elements.

Comment: Corrected it :)

Comment: To your question, there are two non-isomorphic groups of order $6$ so just writing down a bijection doesn't solve the problem.  And you probably don't want to use the fact that there are only two non-isomorphic groups unless you can prove that, so it's best to prove that your map is an isomorphism.

Comment: Were you given that $f$ or did you choose it yourself and if so, how?

Comment: Ok, i know that for it to be a homomorphism, it has to satisfy $f(a+b)=f(a)\cdot f(b)$. How can I show this?

Comment: I mapped it myself, creating two tables.

Comment: Well, these tables prove your equality, don't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ has six elements and is abelian,but the only abelian group having six elements is $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$,another way (following your approach) is to prove that $3$ has order 6,since homomorphisms of cyclic groups are entirely determined by the image of generator.

Answer (score 0):

By construction, your bijection $f$ sends $n1\in\Bbb Z_6$ to $3^n\in U(\Bbb Z_7)$ so it is an homomorphism.